# How to map URL to port and modified URL?

Tags: url, nginx, port, lighttpd, forwarding

How do I map www.somesite.com/api(.*) to www.somesite.com/$1:9000?
(I need to map /api to Play framework application running @ port 9000)

I did the following:

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/api" {
    proxy.server = ( "" =>
    ( ( "host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 9000 ) ) )
}
```

This gets me to somesite.com/api:9000 when I go to somesite.com/api, and I get "Action not found: For request 'GET /api'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easily accomplished using Nginx:

```
    location /api/ {
            rewrite   ^/api(/.*)$ $1 break;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
    }
```

Comment: This is not complete solution, and it won't work on ubuntu.