# How to run a Ghost blog alongside ReactJS app?

Tags: reactjs, ghost

I have an app/website based on Node + ReactJS. I'd like to add a blog to it via custom-installed Ghost.org. After hours of googling I still have no clue how to do it, so I'm really looking for starting points, e.g.:

-How do I "combine" the two, so that I have the blog on myapp.com/blog (not on a subdomain)?
-How do I route to the blog from my React app?
-Would it even be possible if my app runs on different node version than what ghost requires?

Any pointers would be appreciated

Comment: What web server are you using? Apache? nginx?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't prove this but I'm pretty sure it can works.

If you're using nginx you should follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22671726/1301872) and configure nginx like this:

```
location /blog/ {
        rewrite   ^/blog(/.*)$ $1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9000; # You should configure ghost to run on port 9000
}
```